# Problem with LCID and UK dates DVWP

Tags: data-view-web-part

I am trying to apply the UK format to a date in a data view web part using the following method:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate) ,2057 ,3)" />
```

However, this seems to still be trying to revert to US dates (1033) which means the long dates are wrong.

Anyone know why this may happen and have a fix?

Regional settings are set to UK and other dates across the site seem to be displaying correctly. If I go to the calendar and edit the date, I know it works as it sits in October quite nicely where as a date of 6th October ends up as the 10th June in my DVWP.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: just wondered if there was any fix for this as I have come accross the same problem. My Region Settings are UK across the board. My DVWP uses the UK formatting for the date field, however the 2/4/2012 is showing as 4th Feb 2012. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem with LCID 1037 and I wonder if you ever found a solution for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in my US-en (1033) environment, and it seems to work fine. (I copied your XSL so that even the commas were in the exact same place.)

```
<xsl:value-of select="@EventDate" />::<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate) ,2057 ,3)" />
```

This is what is returned:

```
2010-10-01T05:00:00Z::01 October 2010 
2010-10-02T05:00:00Z::02 October 2010
2010-10-03T05:00:00Z::03 October 2010
2010-10-04T05:00:00Z::04 October 2010
2010-10-05T05:00:00Z::05 October 2010
2010-10-06T05:00:00Z::06 October 2010
2010-10-07T05:00:00Z::07 October 2010
2010-10-08T05:00:00Z::08 October 2010
2010-10-09T05:00:00Z::09 October 2010
2010-10-10T05:00:00Z::10 October 2010
2010-10-11T05:00:00Z::11 October 2010
2010-10-12T05:00:00Z::12 October 2010
2010-10-13T05:00:00Z::13 October 2010
```

As you can see, the underlying data in the @EventDate column is Zulu time. Now, I'm assuming that you're working with a Calendar, and therefore, the built-in Site Column @EventDate. If it's your own column, then there could be other formats in it.

Try the XSL above and see what *you* see.

Answer (score 1):

The output from your select="@EventDate" isn't the full ISO format (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ) - wonder if that has something to do with it...

Comment: Agreed, this seems likely - I've used the FormatDate function like that in the DVWP before without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, any date in the first 12 days will try and use a US date format but after that it works fine.

i.e.  06/10 = 10th June
13/10 = 13th October

Wierd

Matt

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the FormatDate function.  I assume those numbers after it localize it to your region.  Is that the correct LCID?

From your hint, it really does sound like the function has made the assumption of a US date for input MM/dd/yyyy.  What if you pass in the date as ISO-8601, so its independent of any locale?  yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss Z

Answer (score 0):

```
06/10/2010 00:00:: 10 June 2010 
13/10/2010 12:00:: 13 October 2010  
20/10/2010 12:00:: 20 October 201
```

Ok so i did the short code for it and I got

```
06/10/2010 00:00:: 06/10/2010   
13/10/2010 12:00:: 10/13/2010   
20/10/2010 12:00:: 10/20/2010
```

This is so strange and makes no sense what so ever.

Someone help.

Thanks

Matt

(Marc - Can you try changing your region to UK and see if you still get the right output?)